# Flutter + FCM: onBackgroundMessage vs onMessageOpenedApp

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Recently I've been working on connecting flutter with FCM.
While reading [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#apple_platforms_and_android) I red:

> Handle background messages by registering a `onBackgroundMessage` handler.

,but later reading [flutterfire docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/#handling-interaction) I've found:

> The firebase-messaging package provides two ways to handle this interaction:
>
> 1. (...)
> 2. `onMessageOpenedApp`: A Stream which posts a RemoteMessage when the application is opened from a background state.

I understood, that first function is to handle notification when app is in background (whenever user interacted with it or not) and 2nd one is to handle tapping on notification when app is in background.
Correct me if that's wrong.

But if I'm right about it, then wouldn't using both functions cause redundancy? `onBackgroundMessage` runs independently (as separate isolate), so if user taps on notification when app is closed, would both functions be fired?

Right now I use `flutter_local_notifications` to save notifications that were not interacted with (and app was in background/terminated) and check for them when app is started/resumed by user. If I was correct in above conclusion as well, then should I check inside `onMessageOpenedApp` if clicked notification was already handled by `onBackgroundMessage` (and thus saved in local storage)?

Please, help me clarify that matter.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a message was handled by `onBackgroundMessage`, it won't cause a notification to appear (unless you manually do so, e.g. through `flutter_local_notifications`), so it won't appear in `onMessageOpenedApp`.

`onMessageOpenedApp` is called only when app is in background (but not terminated!) and user taps on notification that was delivered previously (so, since when app is in foreground all messages are sent to `onMessage`, it had to be delivered when app was in background).

Comment: This doesn't match what I'm seeing. If a message containing a notification is received while the app is in the background, a notification is displayed regardless of whether the message was handled via `onBackgroundMessage` or not. Leaving me to wonder if the same message will then be handled again by `onMessageOpenedApp` when the notification is clicked.